# Serial port control through a shell script

Tags: bash, serial-port

I am developing an orientation controller. I have a development board which communicates with the sensor (a compass) through I2C. Because the board is pretty limited (no OS), I developed a simple program to receive things like: (1) 'get 0' to read the sensor's register 0; (2) 'set 0 10' to set the sensor's register 0 with the value 10. For each of these cases the board returns: (1) 'Done: 10.' (register 0 has the value 10); (2) 'Done.'; and (3) 'error: ...' in case of error. With this, I am trying to develop a shell script (bash) to send commands and retrieve data in order to understand the sensor and develop the controller.

My problem is with the following code:

```
# read device output in the background.
head -n 1 /dev/ttyUSB0 &
head=$!

# (#1): without the following stmt I get:
#   head: cannot open `/dev/ttyUSB0' for reading: : Protocol error
sleep 0.1

# send command to the device.
echo "get 0" > /dev/ttyUSB0

# (#2) wait for head.
while kill -0 $head 2>/dev/null ; do : ; done
```

I guess (#1) is caused by a read/write conflict between 'head' and 'echo', but I don't know why and I have no idea on how to solve it.

Another issue is in (#2) where I would like to use a timeout. I've tried something like:

```
timeout 1 bash -c "while kill -0 $head 2>/dev/null ; do : ; done"
```

But I get: ``` Timeout: aborting command ``bash'' with signal 9 ``` and the program gets stuck.

By the way, before the code above is executed I do initialize the serial port with:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb
```

EDIT: I don't want an interactive terminal. I want to use this routine as necessary. This routine is the necessary foundation of the controller (read/write sensor's registers) which later will be implemented in the board.

Comment: Have you seen the following post? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/how-to-connect-to-a-serial-port-as-simple-as-using-ssh

Comment: Why don't you just `wait $head`?

Comment: @jpe: I don't want an interactive shell. I want to use this routine only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To solve (#1) I modified the routine to use a fd:

```
# $1: the device filename, eg. /dev/ttyS0
# $2: number of lines to read before exit.

exec 3<>$1

head -n "$2" 0<&3 &
wait_pid=$!

cat - 1>&3

wait $wait_pid

exec 3>&-
```

**EDIT**: To solve (#2), instead of providing the routine with timeout support I delegate that responsibility to the caller. However, in case of timeout we need to clean up. For that I've added the following after `wait_pid=$!`:

```
trap="if kill -0 $wait_pid ; then kill -TERM $wait_pid ; fi"
trap "$trap" SIGINT SIGKILL SIGTERM
```