# Read the last line of serial in OpenWrt using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, arduino, openwrt

I have my Arduino on /dev/ttyATH0. Arduino permanently sends data like "255" with a newline. How to read the last line from Arduino? I tried using     tail -1 /dev/ttyATH0     but I should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to resume the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach**

OpenWRT and especially LuCI is all about lua. You can see, if OpenWRT provides [libs232](https://github.com/ynezz/librs232) or [ul_serial](https://github.com/edartuz/ul_serial).

Another option were to use Python and [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

Both variants will give a much more flexible way to handle serial communication.

Comment: But are there any direct ways, without using LUA or Python? I'd like using shell command...

Comment: This is an interesting [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.system/fXHq-ijPgIU) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204860/serial-port-control-through-a-shell-script)